# Getting records from Stored Procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have mad a stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_games_menu` //

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_games_menu`
(
IN currplayer INT,
OUT gameid INT,
OUT lastdraw INT,
OUT playertiles TEXT,
OUT oppnation INT,
OUT oppname VARCHAR(100),
OUT fdraw INT,
OUT playerpoints INT,
OUT infopop INT,
OUT oppTiles TEXT,
OUT tabletiles TEXT,
OUT playerturn INT,
OUT newtabletiles TEXT,
OUT profileimg VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
SELECT 
    gp.fk_game_id
  , gp.player_tiles
  , gp.infoPop
  , gp.first_draw
  , gp.player_points
  , g.table_tiles
  , g.new_tiles
  , gp2.last_draw_type
  , gp2.player_turn
  , gp2.player_tiles
  , u.country
  , u.username
  , u.profileimg
INTO 
    gameid
  , playertiles
  , infopop
  , fdraw
  , playerpoints
  , tabletiles
  , newtabletiles
  , lastdraw
  , playerturn
  , oppTiles
  , oppnation
  , oppname
  , profileimg
FROM nf_gameplayer gp
INNER JOIN nf_games g 
ON gp.fk_game_id = g.game_id
INNER JOIN nf_gameplayer gp2
ON  gp.fk_game_id = gp2.fk_game_id
AND gp.fk_player_id != gp2.fk_player_id
INNER JOIN nf_users u
ON gp2.fk_player_id = u.id
WHERE gp.fk_player_id = currplayer 
AND   g.invite=0 
AND   g.deleteby != currplayer 
ORDER BY g.lastdraw;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am then trying to call it like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mytest');

$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL get_games_menu(1, @gameid,@playertiles,@infopop,@fdraw,@playerpoints,@tabletiles,@newtabletiles,@lastdraw,@playerturn,@opptiles,@oppnation,@oppname,@profileimg)' );
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT @gameid,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL');
while($row = $rs->fetch_object())
{
    echo $row['gameid']-'<br>';
}
```

But I am not getting any records. When doing a normal mysql I get 9 records...

What am I doing wrong. (New with stored procedures).

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Sproc parameters cannot be optional.  You must provide them all in your `CALL` statement.

Comment: No error messages? When you call the procedure via MySQL cmd line it works just like you have it here?

Answer (score 0):

CALL get_games_menu(1, @gameid) 
Pass values for all the variables you have in the get_games_menu .
Else set
CALL get_games_menu(1, @gameidm,NULL,NULL,etc..)

Comment: I have have now tried that (See edited question) but still no result?

Comment: Try ...   while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {the same code }